# Dismiss action to custom segue

Tags: ios, swift

I have this code:

```
@IBAction func cancelAction(_ sender: Any) {
    self.dismiss(animated: true) { }
}
```

Can it be done differently perhaps with custom segue?

Thanks

Comment: What's wrong with that code? Seems reasonable to me. You might be able to use an unwind segue instead, but I don't see a problem with the code you posted.

Comment: I need it in more places. It Seems tedious. I am looking for reusable solutions.

Comment: You could define an extension to UIViewController that implemented that function then, and it would be available to all view controllers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define your custom segue like this:

```
class DismissSegue: UIStoryboardSegue {

    override func perform() {
        if let p = source.presentingViewController {
            p.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

}
```

On your storyboard, drag the action segue of the button to the view controller itself and select Custom > Dismiss, make sure the Module of the segue is set to your current project Module (if it's empty):

[image]